# How to make two rows inside one row react-virtualized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I need to make for some rows react-virtualized from table, create 2 rows,  1 row it is row react-virtualized second row it is my custom row
Ho to do it, maybe has some example?

I tried use defaultTableRowRenderer() function,as far as I understand, this embeds newlines in react-virtualized table, but I not need this

its must look like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyPT5.png)

My code look like this

```
return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height: "90vh" }}>
        <AutoSizer>
          {({ width, height }) => (
            <TableVirtualized
              headerHeight={70}
              height={height}
              overscanRowCount={5}
              rowHeight={ 80}
              rowCount={rowItems.length}
              rowGetter={({index}) => rowItems[index]}
              width={width}
              className={className}
              rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
          
            >
              {headerTitles.map((v:any, i:any)=>{
                  const key = Object.keys(v);
                  return (
                      <Column 
                        label={v[`${key}`]} 
                        dataKey={key} 
                        width={200} 
                        cellRenderer={(v: any)=> cell(v)}
                        key={i} 
                        headerRenderer={()=> formatHeader(v[`${key}`])}
                      />
                  )
                }
                )}
            </TableVirtualized>
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
```

this my rowRender function. I think this is a bad way, because row react-virtualized height is fixed

```
  const rowRenderer = (props: any) => {
    const { index, style, className, key, rowData } = props;

      if(rowData.attributes){
        return (
          <div className={cellProps.attributes.className}>
            {defaultTableRowRenderer(props)}
            <div className='blabla'>1</div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    return defaultTableRowRenderer(props);
}
```

Comment: Hi, You could provide a codesandbox link let question more clearly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added more to my question